# Get webelement text in QAF

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bdd, qaf

I would like to get the text of a particular webelement in a web page in QAF. With selenium we use

```
element(by.id('id')).getAttribute('value');
```

How do I write the above code in QAF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same way as you are using in normal selenium for example:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id")).getAttribute('value');
```

In addition to that, with qaf there are multiple ways to achieve it.
Let say your locator is `id=id`, To create element object you can use one of the following way:

```
new QAFExtendedWebElement(loc)
//or
driver.findElement(loc)
```

short hand:

```
import static com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.ElementFactory.$;


$(loc)
```

To get value in code

```
   String val = $(loc).getAttribute("value");
```

To assert/verify/wait value in code

```
    $(loc).verifyValue(expectedValue);
    $(loc).assertValue(expectedValue);
    $(loc).waitForValue(expectedValue);
```

Using inbuilt [steps](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support/blob/master/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/step/CommonStep.java) from qaf-support:

```
    import static com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.CommonStep.*;

    verifyValue(loc, value);
    assertValue(loc, value);
    waitForValue(loc, value);
```

[Steps](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support/blob/master/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/step/CommonStep.java) to assert/verify/wait value in `BDD`

```
    verify 'loc' value is 'expectedValue'
    assert 'loc' value is 'expectedValue'
    wait until 'loc' value is 'expectedValue'
```

Comment: String val = $(loc).getAttribute("value");  This Worked.   Thanks